# How to imitate datanavigator control feature?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net datatable to which I'm trying to add a new row when a button is clicked

My code is :

```
public sub NewButtonClicked(Sender as Object, e as eventargs) handles ButtonNew.click
    NewRow = MyDataTable.NewRow 
end sub 

public sub ConfirmButtonClicked(Sender as object, e as eventargs) handles Confirm.Click
    for i=0 to MyTextBoxesList.count-1
        NewRow(MyTextBoxesList(i).Name) = MyTextBoxesList(i).Text)
    next 

    MyDataTable.Rows.Add(NewRow)
end sub
```

The problem when I do this is that, when I click ButtonNew, the new row is created in the memory but it's not reflected in the form. Which means that the DataNavigator does not move one step and clears the bound textboxes in order to type new values unlike, clicking new row in the DataNavigator itself.

Attached a video for comparison between "manual" action and DataNavigator action.

[Video Comparison](https://www.dropbox.com/s/di9bies5ambg10x/2013-11-21%2021h51_46.mp4)

Does anyone know how to imitate the DataNavigator new button action ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is that you haven't actually added the new row to the datatable until the MyDataTable.Rows.Add(NewRow) so there isn't a position that you can move to.  The navigator adds the new row and moves to the last position.  Could you let the navigtor handle it and perhaps have a vaidation check to verify the row is ok or else delete it ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When the navigator adds the new row to the table, how come that the table accepts the row added even if some columns with the property AllowDBNull = false, are empty at the moment of the insertion ?

Comment: When you first click the navigators AddNew button a new datarow is created but isn't added to the datatable until you navigate to a new row.